# Obtener el state de redux en un componente

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

Estoy empezando con redux y react y estoy un poco confundido con lo siguiente:

Tengo un objeto `auth`en el store de `redux`con los valores:

```
isLoggedIn(pin):false
accountCreated(pin):false
user(pin):null
token(pin):null
```

Y tengo el componente `Main.js` que es el inicio de la aplicacion.

```
import React from 'react';
import MainHeader from 'components/MainHeader';
import Footer from 'components/Footer';

const Main = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className='container-fluid bg-gradient-info'>
      <MainHeader />
      <main className='p-3'>
        {children}
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

> Lo que yo quiero es obtener una variable que contenga el valor de `store.auth.isLoggedIn`para, en base al valor de esa variable, redirigir al `Login`o al `Inicio`de mi app.

Entiendo que con la funcion mapStateToProps podria hacer algo como:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
   loggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main)
```

> Y de esta manera (creo) estaría conectado desde mi componente con el `store`de `redux`. No sé cómo hacer para obtener dentro de todo el componente una variable `loggedIn`que devuelva `true`o `false` de acuerdo con el valor de `store.auth.isLoggedIn`. Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo visto, estás haciendo todo bien, siendo así, te voy a aclarar lo siguiente para que entiendas como puedes utilizar estos props que inyecta `redux` en tu componente:

1. La función `connect` de `redux` le pasa como *argumento* a tu función `mapStateToProps` todo el *estado global* de tu aplicación alojado en `redux` y a su vez inyecta el objeto que devuelve esta última función como props (como su nombre lo indica, un "estado mapeado a props") a tu componente.

Con esta aclaración, si tienes lo siguiente:

```
const Main = ({ children, loggedIn }) => {
    // Aquí tendrías acceso a los valores que inyectes a través de
    // mapStateToProps como props de tu component
    if (!loggedIn) {
        // TODO: El usuario no está autenticado por lo tanto
        // no puede visualizar dicho componente.
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div className='container-fluid bg-gradient-info'>
            <MainHeader />
            <main className='p-3'>
                {children}
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
    loggedIn: state.auth.isLoggedIn
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: Impecable! Muchísimas gracias por ese aporte!